# Is my GPU or PSU going out?

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, visual-artifacts

So, the screen started showing artifacts and then suddenly went out but the sound was still working. Thinking it was just the game I was playing, I tried to ctrl+alt+del, esc, and alt+f4 out of it but nothing seemed to work. I restarted the computer and it went to the Windows splash screen with lines of artifacts going down the screen and didn't proceed further. I restarted it again and went into the bios, which was also covered in artifacts, and switched the video output from the graphics card to igfx, switched the cable over, and restarted the computer. Now it seems to be working fine, no artifacts and it goes past the splash screen.

Now my question is: is the GTX560 starting to die or is the PSU not putting out the power that the graphics card needs to run properly?

Motherboard: Asus Maximus VI Gene-Z/Gen3

Processor: Intel i7-3770

Graphics Card: Nvidia GTX560

PSU: 550W

Comment: If it was the PSU your computer wouldn't even turn on, your GPU is bad, use the intel GPU to confirm

Comment: I thought that if the PSU couldn't provide enough power then some of the components don't completely shut down, they just act pretty weird.

Answer (score 2):

Your GPU is at fault.  The fact you see artifacts in the BIOS indicates this isn't a driver issue, and you further confirmed the problem is caused by your GPU by switching to your integrated graphics and observing the problem went away.

Before counting the GPU as a loss, examine it for excessive dust or a non- or poorly-operating fan.  It could be overheating which could possibly be addressed without replacing it.

Comment: Looking in the computer, the fans are working, but I'm going to take it out tomorrow and look to see if there is dust on some of the more interior parts. I guess I was needing a new card anyway.

Comment: [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6513947_troubleshoot-nvidia-graphic-cards.html?dmsp=manual) might be somewhat helpfull.

Comment: Or you might want to try the [VMST (Video Memory Stress Test)](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/video_memory_stress_test.html)

Comment: The problem with running a stress test on the graphics card is I can not get past the splash screen if I use the GPU. I have to use the one in the MoBo to be able to use the computer.

Answer (score -1):

Could be **literally*** a million things

- If theres very little dust and your computer is sandwiched between the desk and the wall, and otherwise in a space that you yourself would not be comfortable in = then you have bad cooling and mmmmaybe your GPU is dead, if not more.
- If theres dust: It overheated and died (probably)
- If theres no dust, coolings fine: But you run Many USB devices: Maybe your PSU choked your GPU like a ____ at a ____ in _____.

  - If none of those are the case, we usually blame Bob. But dont tell him that, hes still convinced aliens are to blame, and if hes right, then your machine has been abducted before.

Comment: If the overheating was the case, what can I change to help prevent this on the next card? Better fans or maybe better cable management(its kind of a mess in there) to help with air flow?